# Django tables - data in rows

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a simple loop that looks at the domains and populates the sub domains column.

The first column has one domain and one subdomain. So it works fine. 
The second domain (A6) has two subdomains (A.6.1 and A.6.2). However, the A.6.2 gets pushed to the far right. It should be under A.6.1 and A6 rows should be merged so the domain is only repeated once.

So the table should be

```
Domain          Subdomain
A5              A.5.1
A6              A.6.1
                A.6.2
                A.6.3
                etc.
```

The template tags are:

```
<table class="table table-sm">
        <tr>
            <th>Domain ID</th>
            <th>Sub Domain ID</th>
        </tr>
        {% for domain in domains %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ domain.domain_id }}</td>
                {% for sub_domain in domain.subdomain_set.all %}
                <td>{{ sub_domain.subDomain_id }}</td>                
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

The above code gives me this:
[image: table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct template for the case is

```
<table class="table table-sm">
        <tr>
            <th>Domain ID</th>
            <th>Sub Domain ID</th>
        </tr>
        {% for domain in domains %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ domain.domain_id }}</td>
                <td>{% for sub_domain in domain.subdomain_set.all %}{{ sub_domain.subDomain_id }}<br/>{% endfor %}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Comment: Thank you. If I add more columns with text, the alignement is all messed up. Is it possible to add A.6.1, A.6.2 etc. in its own row while keeping A6 merged in its cell?

Comment: Django templates just output HTML, so I think you can get some basic information how it works using https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp